# Rounding a Tuple

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, rounding

Having trouble figuring out how to round my final outputs of the tuple to 2 decimal places. Any suggestions??? What I have for my code is as follows:

```
import random
random.randint(0,10)

def a():
    counter=0
    result=[]
    total_score = 0

while(counter<10000):
    i = random.randint(0,10)
    while i not in [1,2,3]:
        if i in [4,5,6]:
            total_score = total_score + i
            i=random.randint(0,10)
        elif i in [7,8,9,10]:
            total_score = total_score + i*2
            i=random.randint(0,10)
        else: 
            total_score = total_score/2
            i=random.randint(0,10)
    counter += 1
    result.append(total_score)

a=sum(result)/len(result)
b=max(result)
return(a,b)

print(a())
```

Comment: Your formatting here is not correct

Comment: `round(6.31514, 2)` gives `6.32`

Comment: you can just round them on the return `return(round(a, 2),round(b, 2))`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is round them on the return or round them when the variables are defined. You can also skip the variables entirely, with a small performance improvement (I think).

For the normal rounding (replace the return statement with this):

```
return (round(a, 2), round(b, 2))
```

Or, you can do this:

```
return (round(sum(result) / len(result), 2), round(max(result), 2))
```